# C# - How to create progress bars dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, webclient, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to develop a little program which can support several uploads simultaneously. However, I'm facing a problem : if I have one file uploading, there is a progress bar; but when I put more files to upload, I don't know how to create progress bars for each file independently and how to automatically add additional bars on multiple uploads.
I use `WebClient` class with `UploadFileAsync`.

`String file` is the path needed for uploading and `uploadForm` is the `Form` where I would show progress bars and do uploads.

EDIT : final code to make it functional

```
private void UploadEnProgres(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e, String file, ProgressBar nouvelleProgressBar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} octet sur {2} au total. {3} % envoyés...", file, e.BytesSent, e.TotalBytesToSend, e.ProgressPercentage);
    nouvelleProgressBar.Value = (int)((e.BytesSent * 100) / e.TotalBytesToSend);
}

private void UploadFini(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e, String file, ProgressBar nouvelleProgressBar, TextBox nouvelleTextBox, Int32 hauteur)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled) || (e.Error != null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : ERREUR -- {1}", file, e.Error);
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : upload terminé, statut : ", file, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));
    uploadForm.Controls.Remove(nouvelleProgressBar);
    uploadForm.Controls.Remove(nouvelleTextBox);
    hauteur = 12;
}

public void HTTPClientUpload(String file)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upload button.");
    WebClient clientUpload = new WebClient();
    String authInfo;
    authInfo = utilisateur + ":" + motDePasse;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    clientUpload.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

    // CODE HTTP UPLOAD

    this.hauteur += 22;

    ProgressBar nouvelleProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
    nouvelleProgressBar.Size = new Size(180, 20);
    nouvelleProgressBar.Maximum = 100;
    nouvelleProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
    nouvelleProgressBar.Location = new Point(258, hauteur);
    nouvelleProgressBar.Visible = true;
    uploadForm.Controls.Add(nouvelleProgressBar);

    TextBox nouvelleTextBox = new TextBox();
    nouvelleTextBox.Size = new Size(180, 20);
    nouvelleTextBox.Location = new Point(70, hauteur);
    nouvelleTextBox.Text = Path.GetFileName(file);
    nouvelleTextBox.Enabled = false;
    uploadForm.Controls.Add(nouvelleTextBox);

    clientUpload.Headers.Add("Chemin", "/" + identifiantAppareil + file.Replace(@"\", "/"));
    clientUpload.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => UploadFini(sender, e, Path.GetFileName(file), nouvelleProgressBar, nouvelleTextBox, hauteur));
    clientUpload.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => UploadEnProgres(sender, e, Path.GetFileName(file), nouvelleProgressBar));
    clientUpload.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(urlServeur, "v1/ul"), file);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking...

Comment: Oh... Sorry. I'll try to be concise: I would upload multiple files with their own progress bar to display them in a form (a filename / its progress bar; another filename / its progress bar; a third filename / its progress bar; ...)
Is it better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Create a new progressbar each time you start an upload in code
var progressbar = new ProgressBar()

//add it to the form
uploadForm.Controls.Add(progressbar );
```

you'll need to look into how you group / position them

Comment: Don't forget to remove it after the upload completes.

Comment: Not at all. This answer is just giving you the minimum you need to programmatically create and add each bar. You still have plenty to work out like work out how to position them properly, how to keep track of the right one for each upload and as matan7890 said remembering to remove it when done. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For organization, I would suggest a TableLayoutPanel to add newly created controls to.